# How to clear cookies of applications running in iPhone and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, cookies

Is there a way to clear cookies of a given application in iPhone and Android. I know this can be done by code, but I need to know if this can be done from the Phone itself?

In Android clicking on the "Clear data" button in Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > ApplicaitonName will log me out of the application. Does this actually delete the cookies?

Most importantly,  how is it done in iPhone?

http://sqastuff.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a way to do this on iPhone as far as i know because each app can save it's cookies in a different way, also, you're really limited in the way you can interact with other iPhone app, so even if apps saved cookies the same way you'd probably still be out of luck.